# How to switch between different states with Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, state, fft, frequency, led

I've been trying to visualize the different frequencies with a SoundSensor and LED's for some time now. My problem is the following: As soon as a frequency range is activated e.g. `if (frequency > 82 && frequency < 330)` it should stay activated until there is no noise or another frequency range is detected and switches accordingly.

Unfortunately, it remains glowing at the moment, even if there is no more noise.

```cpp
#include <FreqMeasure.h>

const int LED = 6;
int j = 255;
int i = 25;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  FreqMeasure.begin(); //Measures on pin 8 by default
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
}

double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
bool state = false;
float frequency;
int continuity = 0;

void loop() {

  if (FreqMeasure.available()) {
    // average several reading together
    sum = sum + FreqMeasure.read();
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 100) {
      frequency = FreqMeasure.countToFrequency(sum / count);
      Serial.println(frequency);
      sum = 0;
      count = 0;
    }
  }

  if (frequency > 82 && frequency < 330)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Bass");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 28);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

  if (frequency > 98 && frequency < 392)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Bariton");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 56);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

  if (frequency > 131 && frequency < 440)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Tenor");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 84);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

  if (frequency > 165 && frequency < 659)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Männeralt");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 112);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

  if (frequency > 196 && frequency < 659)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Alt");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 140);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

  if (frequency > 196 && frequency < 698)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Mezzosopran");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 168);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

 if (frequency > 262 && frequency < 880)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Sopran");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 196);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

   if (frequency > 415 && frequency < 466)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Kopfstimme");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 196);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 0);
  }

  if (frequency > 698 && frequency < 1175)
  {
    continuity++;
    Serial.print("Continuity -> ");
    Serial.println(continuity);
    Serial.println("Kastraten");
    frequency = 0;
  }

  if (continuity >= 1 && state == false)
  {
    state = true;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned ON");
    analogWrite(LED, 196);
  }

  if (continuity >= 2 && state == true)
  {
    state = false;
    continuity = 0;
    Serial.println("Light Turned OFF");
    analogWrite(LED, 255);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, state);
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't make to much sense to me. you have overlapping frequency ranges but you set frequency = 0 once it hits the first frequency bin.